# Getting 504 Error while opening GCP AI Jupyter notebook instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I have been getting a **504 Error** while trying to open a Jupyter Notebook instance on GCP AI platform. I have restarted and reset the instance several times for 2 days, and I still get the same error. Does anyone know how to overcome the 504 error and get access to my data on the Jupyter notebook instance? [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAFUA.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think that in this case the best thing to do is to create a new AI Notebook. You can access to the VM through SSH, copy the data, the python notebooks and whatever you have there and move to another fresh AI notebook.

If you are not used to bash (Linux command line interface) I can give you the necessary information to connect to your VM and perform all the commands to achieve this.

Waiting for your answer!

Comment: Thanks Kim. That was what I ended up doing.

Comment: @MershackOkoe Can you paste the commands you used for this? I'm having similar problems

Comment: I created a GCS bucked and I copied the files there. Look at the following link to perform the copy command --> https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the latest Deep Learning VM Image version 52+.
We corrected a problem which could lead to this situation.

Answer (score -1):

Creating fresh new notebook seems to be the only option here.